# Problem involving Characteristic Function and Sequence of sets.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $E_{*}=\lim\inf E_n$ and $E^*=\lim \sup E_n$ where $E_n$ is a sequence of sets. Then we have to show that $$\chi_{E_*}(x)=\lim\inf \chi_{E_n}(x)$$ and $$\chi_{E^*}(x)=\lim\sup\chi_{E_n}(x).$$

I am a little confused with the notation and so I have trouble starting with the proof. I know that $\chi_{E}(x)=1$ if $x\in E$ and $0$ if $x\not \in E.$ But I am not sure what to do here. Any hints would be much appreciated.

**Edit**: After Hint $1.$

Proof: If $x\in E_{*}$ then $\chi_{E_{*}}(x)=1$ and also $x\in \bigcup_{n\geq 1}\bigcap_{j\geq n}E_j.$ Then we would have $\exists n\geq 1\forall j\geq n$ $x\in E_j.$ On the right hand side we have to find the $\lim\inf$ of a numerical sequence $\{0,0,0,...,1,1,...\}$ where for that first $j-1$ positions there is a zero and one elsewhere. Thus $\lim \inf $ of this sequence is $1.$ Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: The description of the sequence is not correct: after index $n$ all the terms are $1$, and before index $n$, the values can be $0$ or $1$. You also need to handle the case where $x\not\in E_*$

Answer (score 1):

For a fixed $x$ the following statements are equivalent:

- $\chi_{\liminf E_n}(x)=1$
- $x\in\liminf E_n$.
- The set $\{n\in\mathbb N\mid x\notin E_n\}$ is finite.
- The set $\{n\in\mathbb N\mid\chi_{E_n}(x)=0\}$ is finite.
- $\liminf\chi_{E_n}(x)=1$

This can be 'dualized' to achieve a sortlike result for $\limsup$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
To prove that $\chi_A(x) = \varphi(x)$, prove that
$$x\in A \Longrightarrow \varphi(x) = 1\quad \text{and}\quad x\not\in A \Longrightarrow \varphi(x) = 0$$

Comment: Please see the edit...